# RQuantLib: Apply option pricing to data list

Tags: r, quantlib

So I am using RQuantLib's AmericanOption function. It works fine if the input are single numbers, for example:

```
AmericanOption(type = 'call', underlying = 73.59, strike = 74, dividendYield  
= 0, riskFreeRate = 0.006, maturity = 0.25, volatility= 0.2, timeSteps = 
150, gridPoints = 149, engine="CrankNicolson")
```

However, since I have time-series data containing the daily data of the same option over time, for example:

```
Time     underlying   strike ...
10-01      73           74
10-02      74           74
10-03      75           74
...
```

obviously then I want to apply the pricing function to every single data point and output the result as a new data frame containing the results for every day.

And since I already have underlying and strike prices as data lists, what I did was creating sequence of 0 for dividend ("dividend"), sequence of 0.006 for risk free ("riskfree"), and decay maturity as:

```
end <- 21/252 
interval <- 1/252
opmaturity <- seq(0.25, end, by=-interval)
```

(from 3 months to maturity to 1 month to maturity)

So of course I can't just do the following:

```
AmericanOption(type = 'call', underlying = RR$Stock, strike =   
RR$Strike.Price, dividendYield = dividend, riskFreeRate = riskfree, maturity 
= ematurity, volatility= vol, timeSteps = 150, gridPoints = 149, 
engine="CrankNicolson")
```

because the function expects single value input.

So, how do I do this properly to tell the function to input the time-series data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to use the `mapply` function as follow

```
mapply(AmericanOption, type = 'call', underlying = RR$Stock, strike =   
RR$Strike.Price, dividendYield = dividend, riskFreeRate = riskfree, maturity 
= ematurity, volatility= vol, timeSteps = 150, gridPoints = 149, 
engine="CrankNicolson")
```